# StaticFileModule on IIS 7.5 on windows server 2008 intercepts unexpected requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a little problem here.
We are developing ASP.NET MVC 3 application.
This is my production server system.webServer section:

```
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<rewrite><rules><rule name="http to https" stopProcessing="true"><match url="(.*)" /><conditions><add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" /></conditions><action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Found" /></rule></rules></rewrite>
<urlCompression dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="false" doStaticCompression="false" doDynamicCompression="false" />
<caching enabled="true" enableKernelCache="true" maxCacheSize="0" maxResponseSize="262144">
  <profiles>
    <add extension=".png" policy="CacheUntilChange" varyByHeaders="" varyByQueryString="" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
    <add extension=".gif" policy="CacheUntilChange" varyByHeaders="" varyByQueryString="" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
    <add extension=".ico" policy="CacheUntilChange" varyByHeaders="" varyByQueryString="" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
    <add extension=".css" policy="CacheUntilChange" varyByHeaders="" varyByQueryString="" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
    <add extension=".js" policy="CacheUntilChange" varyByHeaders="" varyByQueryString="" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
  </profiles>
</caching>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
  <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
  <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
</modules>
<handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script">
  <!-- clear all handlers, prevents executing code file extensions, prevents returning any file contents -->
  <clear />
  <add name="WebResourceHandler" path="WebResource.axd" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  <add name="PageHandlerFactory-Integrated" path="*.aspx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" />
  <add name="WebServices" path="*.asmx" verb="*" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  <add verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" path="*.css" name="StaticCss" />
  <add verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" path="*.jpg" name="StaticJpg" />
  <add verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" path="*.jpeg" name="StaticJpeg" />
  <add verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" path="*.gif" name="StaticGif" />
  <add verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" path="*.ico" name="StaticIco" />
  <add verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" path="*.png" name="StaticPng" />
  <add verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" path="*.js" name="StaticJs" />
  <add verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" path="*.htm" name="StaticHtm" />
  <add verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" path="*.html" name="StaticHtml" />
  <add verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" path="*.swf" name="StaticSwf" />
  <add verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" path="*.ttf" name="StaticTtf" />
  <add verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" path="*.eot" name="StaticEof" />
  <add verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" path="*.woff" name="StaticWoff" />
  <add verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" path="*.svg" name="StaticSvg" />
  <add verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" path="*.cab" name="StaticCab" />
  <add verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" path="*.exe" name="StaticExe" />
  <add verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" path="*.msi" name="StaticMsi" />
  <!-- Return 404 for all requests via managed handler. The url routing handler will substitute the mvc request handler when routes match. -->
  <add name="NotFound" path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" preCondition="" requireAccess="Script" />
</handlers>
```

Also we have some MVC routes for handling inmemory content, like

> /Content/InMem/{fileName}/{hash}

so in real we have URL like this

> /Content/InMem/Style.css/0123456789

On my dev pc this works like a charm! But on production server this route is handled by **StaticFileModule** and we have 404 error here.

I've already tried to switch **runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests** and do some manipulation with modules - nothing helps.

Please do not suggest workarounds like "*do not use those file names in URL*" because it also handles any route with **.extension/** in it and part of our logic is broken.

Also i had no luck to reproduce it on any other server i have. Please help!

**Upd:** I have this exactly behavior on local pc if i remove Module *UrlRoutingModule-4.0* from web.config. So this config is somewhat of a solution, but on my production this have no effect.

Comment: Do you have access to the applicationhost.config file of your production server.  Specifically the applicationPool configuration section which contains the managedPipelineMode setting.  If this is set to "Classic" that could explain the behavior.

Comment: @BilalAlam i have full access via rdp. No managedPipelineMode is not set in config and in IIS console i see that pool is set in IntegratedMode